# How to block website in android application

Tags: android, web

I want to block youtube site from my android application.Whenever youtube link clicked, it should be blocked.How is it possible.

Please give me some suggestion

Comment: Do you want to block it on your Android device in general or only within your own application?

Comment: within my application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to controt this in webView, you should use custom WebViewClient.

```
  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.youtube.com")) {
             return true;
         }
         // This is your not youtube site, so do not override; let your WebView load the page

         return false;
    }
    }
```

(http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

In other case when you want to forbid the possibility of transition by the link you should use BroadcastReceiver and control your Intents.